# Is there ngx-bootstrap 'card' component?

Tags: bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap, bootstrap-cards

Is there any existing solution for ngx-bootstrap card component?

If it does not exist, what is the alternative for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the card from bootstrap and not specifically from ngx-bootstrap.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/